# loading SVG in AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

Is anyone familiar with AndEngine and loading svg's?

Right now i am trying to load a background for a scene and it doesnt appear at all for some reason..

Here is th code i am using to load the SVG and attach it to the scene.

```
//In my onLoadResources method
     this.mBuildableTexture = new BuildableBitmapTexture(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
         SVGTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
          this.mSVGTestTextureRegions = SVGTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBuildableTexture, this, "background.svg", 16, 16);

//OnLoadScene method

final BaseTextureRegion baseTextureRegion = this.mSVGTestTextureRegions;
             if(baseTextureRegion instanceof TextureRegion) {
             final TextureRegion Region = (TextureRegion)baseTextureRegion;

             final float centerX = this.mCamera.getWidth() / 2;
             final float centerY = this.mCamera.getHeight() / 2;

             final float x = centerX - SIZE * 0.5f;
             final float y = centerY - SIZE * 0.5f;

             Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(x,y,SIZE,SIZE,Region);
                     /*protected void onInitDraw(final GL10 pGL)
                        {
                           super.onInitDraw(pGL);
                           GLHelper.enableTextures(pGL);
                           GLHelper.enableTexCoordArray(pGL);
                           GLHelper.enableDither(pGL);
                        }
             };*/

            mScene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,backgroundSprite));
             backgroundSprite.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
             }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you including the following statements in your code in loadResources:

```
    try {
        this.mBuildableTexture.build(new BlackPawnTextureBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(1));
    } catch (final TextureAtlasSourcePackingException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBuildableTexture);
```

Comment: I noticed that in the AndEngine example. Wasnt sure if this was the reason why it wasnt working., but i decided not to include it in my code because i didnt think it was neccessary. Maybe this is why it isnt working?!

Comment: Even i dont really know what the function does ... but surely it is necessary to run ... we could conclude that maybe it would be building the texture as per the name suggests .. ;)

Comment: Maybe soo...Its name weirdly "BlackPawn" lol idk, i will try it when i get home andd accept the answer and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I keep getting the the following syntax error under .build.  The method build(ITextureBuilder<IBitmapTextureSource,BitmapTexture>) in the type BuildableTexture<IBitmapTextureSource,BitmapTexture> is not applicable for the arguments (BlackPawnTextureBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource,BitmapTextureAtlas>)

Answer (score 5):

Imo the naming of the BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder class is pretty intuitive, as:

1. It is an implementation ITextureAtlasBuilder interface
2. The class javadoc says:

   - @author Jim Scott (BlackPawn)
   - @since 16:03:01 - 12.08.2010
   - @see http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html

:-)

Comment: Hey Nicolas! Dude you are an amazing coder! I am building an awesome game thanks to your engine. And yeah i just noticed that on the docs. Thats pretty cool how you did that. Thanks alot man. We all owe you!